# Wifi keep disconnected after 5-6 seconds of connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, ubuntu-drivers

I own a lenovo g570 with wifi adapter "Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter(PCI-Express)" 
I installed ubuntu 16.04 on it. It was connected to same wifi- router   during installation and after that. But suddenly it disconnected and showing out of range error. Even router is placed near me. I restarted it and than it connected to router and disconnected within 6 seconds showing same error. While it connect to my mobile hotspot easily. My mobile connects to router while in ubuntu it is out of range